# Starting video playback from reuseable TableViewCell object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `TableView` setup in the `storyboard` and have a prototype cell that I use to hold images and a button to start videos. The path of the video file is a property in each cell object and I would like to play the video when the button is clicked.

Before I began using the table (when I just had button manually drawn on the storyboard) i used the follow to start the movie player `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];` but obviously now that's not possible.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use custom cell to achieve your objective.
You can follow these steps:

1. Create a new class that is a subclass of UITableViewCell and assign it as the class of your custom cell.
2. In your custom class .h file make an IBOutlet for your button.
3. In your main class .m file use this method to play video

   ```
   - (void)playBtnClicked:(id)sender {
   MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:YourURL];
   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
   [movieController.moviePlayer play];
   }
   ```
4. Use this code after you have configured your cell

   ```
   [cell.btn_PlayVideo addTarget:self action:@selector(playBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
   ```

Your should make sure that MediaPlayer.framework is included and MediaPlayer.h file is imported.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is `NSNotificationCenter`. On Click, in your Cell just send notification with index of your row that you can save in button's tag variable.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"playVideo" forKey:@"operationKey"];

   [userInfo setValue: indexPath forKey:@"indexPathRow"];


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"PlayVideoNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

In your ViewController register observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivePlayVideoNotification:) name:@"PlayVideoNotification" object:nil];
```

And do not forget unregister observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"PlayVideoNotification" object:nil];
```

In the method `PlayVideoNotification` do what you need:

```
- (void) receivePlayVideoNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
  NSString *operationKey = [userInfo objectForKey:@"operationKey"];//"playVideo"
  NSString* indexPathRow = [userInfo objectForKey:@"indexPathRow"];  

  //todo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to segue to another ViewController and start the moviePlayerViewController there.
I think you can't just get the IBAction when you click on a TableViewCell.

So try to segue in the InterFaceBuilder, build a ViewController with something like this:
ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *videoFileUrl;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ...

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
}

@end
```